# Angular Material Slider example not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am trying to run angular material example given at [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.slider).
i have tried following example but it is not working for me. through following error in console

Error : 
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module StarterApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'StarterApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

My code is below

test.html
This is html file content

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v0.10.0/angular-material.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v0.10.0/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body layout="column" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <md-content style="margin: 16px; padding:16px">
    <h3>
      RGB <span ng-attr-style="border: 1px solid #333; background: rgb({{color.red}},{{color.green}},{{color.blue}})">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </h3>
    <div layout>
      <div flex="10" layout layout-align="center center">
        <span class="md-body-1">R</span>
      </div>
      <md-slider flex min="0" max="255" ng-model="color.red" aria-label="red" id="red-slider" class>
      </md-slider>
      <div flex="20" layout layout-align="center center">
        <input type="number" ng-model="color.red" aria-label="red" aria-controls="red-slider">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div layout>
      <div flex="10" layout layout-align="center center">
        <span class="md-body-1">G</span>
      </div>
      <md-slider flex ng-model="color.green" min="0" max="255" aria-label="green" id="green-slider" class="md-accent">
      </md-slider>
      <div flex="20" layout layout-align="center center">
        <input type="number" ng-model="color.green" aria-label="green" aria-controls="green-slider">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div layout>
      <div flex="10" layout layout-align="center center">
        <span class="md-body-1">B</span>
      </div>
      <md-slider flex ng-model="color.blue" min="0" max="255" aria-label="blue" id="blue-slider" class="md-primary">
      </md-slider>
      <div flex="20" layout layout-align="center center">
        <input type="number" ng-model="color.blue" aria-label="blue" aria-controls="blue-slider">
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3>Rating: {{rating}}/5 - demo of theming classes</h3>
    <div layout>
      <div flex="10" layout layout-align="center center">
        <span class="md-body-1">default</span>
      </div>
      <md-slider flex md-discrete ng-model="rating1" step="1" min="1" max="5" aria-label="rating">
      </md-slider>
    </div>
    <div layout>
      <div flex="10" layout layout-align="center center">
        <span class="md-body-1">md-warn</span>
      </div>
      <md-slider flex class="md-warn" md-discrete ng-model="rating2" step="1" min="1" max="5" aria-label="rating">
      </md-slider>
    </div>
    <div layout>
      <div flex="10" layout layout-align="center center">
        <span class="md-body-1">md-primary</span>
      </div>
      <md-slider flex class="md-primary" md-discrete ng-model="rating3" step="1" min="1" max="5" aria-label="rating">
      </md-slider>
    </div>
    <h3>Disabled</h3>
    <md-slider ng-model="disabled1" ng-disabled="true" aria-label="Disabled 1"></md-slider>
    <md-slider ng-model="disabled2" ng-disabled="true" aria-label="Disabled 2"></md-slider>
    <h3>Disabled, Discrete</h3>
    <md-slider ng-model="disabled1" ng-disabled="true" step="3" md-discrete min="0" max="10" aria-label="Disabled discrete 1"></md-slider>
    <md-slider ng-model="disabled2" ng-disabled="true" step="10" md-discrete aria-label="Disabled discrete 2"></md-slider>
  </md-content>
</div>
    <!-- Angular Material Dependencies -->

  </body>
</html>
```

test.js
File content

```
angular.module('sliderDemo1', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.color = {
    red: Math.floor(Math.random() * 255),
    green: Math.floor(Math.random() * 255),
    blue: Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
  };
  $scope.rating1 = 3;
  $scope.rating2 = 2;
  $scope.rating3 = 4;
  $scope.disabled1 = 0;
  $scope.disabled2 = 70;
});
```

test.css

```
.sliderdemoBasicUsage input[type="number"] {
  text-align: center; }
```

What is the problem here? and why it is not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have this:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">
```

And this:

```
angular.module('sliderDemo1'
```

Either they should both be StarterApp or they should both be sliderDemo1:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">
angular.module('StarterApp'
```

Or

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="sliderDemo1">
angular.module('sliderDemo1'
```

Also note that the HTML references `{{rating}}` which is never defined. That seems like a mistake in the source code of the example.